# How to fix my macro to create excel tabs based on a table

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro to copy a template macro as many times as there are rows in my table.

However I get the following error:

> Error 429 ActiveX Component Can't Create Object.

It was working fine when I created it a year ago

The part of the code that is giving an issue is the first line starting with lastcell (see code below)

Anybody any idea why it is not working?

Googled on the answer, but could not find why it is not working.

Maybe it has to do with the fact that I created the macro in an older office version (2013) then I am working in right now (2016)

```
Sub Aanmaaktabbladen()
lastcell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bonussen").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 3 To lastcell

With ThisWorkbook

newname = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bonussen").Cells(i, 1).Value

Set wsVOORBEELD = ActiveSheet
wsVOORBEELD.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

ActiveSheet.Name = newname

End With
Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bonussen").Activate
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Bonussen").Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Looking at your code I would say one of the issues is you've got nothing declared.

Try Dim Wb As workbook
Dim Ws as worksheet
Dim Lastcell As integer

Set Wb = Thisworkbook
Set Ws = Wb.worksheets("Bonussen")

Then you can set LastCell as Ws.cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row

Comment: Does the worksheet Bonussen exist in ThisWorkbook? Note that the With block is redundant.

Comment: The Rows.count is unrefererenced and as such takes rows of ActiveSheet. If you "Bonussen" worksheet has less rows than your active sheet you will get an error.